# Jinja python for loop syntax

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a jinja code for python and its giving me an error it doesn't give me in python

```
{% for i, juice in enumerate(a['juice'] for a in television):};
               alert({{ juice }});
            {% endfor %};
```

The Error I'm getting is

```
 expected token ',', got 'for'
```

Comment: Please add a proper error description!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add `:` at the end of the `for` statements in Jinja2. And, you are not properly closing the tag - missing the `%` before the `}`.

Plus, there is no `enumerate()` function in Jinja2, use the [`loop.index0`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for):

```
{% for a in television %}
    {{ loop.index0 }}, {{ a["juice"] }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

If you want to use more Python in the templates, you should probably look at the [`Mako` engine](http://www.makotemplates.org/).